# How to write program in python to generate all n digit numbers with only 4 and 7 as their digits?

Tags: python

I tried generating permutations using itertools.permutations but i am so confused on how to do this for n digits.

Comment: Let's see what you got so far.

Comment: How many digits do you want? You could use the rand() function as well. I would: 
1) generate n numbers between 0 and 1 and store them in an array.
2) if(n[i]==0) n[i]=4; if(n[i]==1) n[i]=7;
3) i'd then sum up all the numbers in n[], multiplying the first digit by 1, the second by 10, the third by 100, etc... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `itertools.product` instead:

```
In [26]: for i in itertools.product(['4', '7'], repeat=2):
   ....:     print int(''.join(i))
   ....:
44
47
74
77
```

The `repeat` argument is your `n`.

Comment: is there any way to convert the output from a tuple into a string or int eg."47" instead of (4,7)

Comment: @KartikKhare: You'd have to make `4` and `7` strings. From there, you could do `int(''.join(i))`.

Comment: Or `reduce(lambda x, y: 10*x + y, (1, 2, 3))`

Comment: @jamylak: Oddly enough, working with a string is almost twice faster than `reduce`.

Comment: @Blender makes sense since `lambda`s are slow, tuples are faster than lists too

Comment: @jamylak: That's what I thought as well, but I cached the list of digits and used a named function and the times didn't really change.

Comment: @Blender oh right, Python must make a sequence out of whatever iterable is given first so it wouldn't matter

Answer (score 1):

I would use binary, if you need all 2-digits numbers with only `7`, `4` as digits:

max 2 digits number in base-2 is `11b` ie `3`, so:

```
0 => 00b
1 => 01b
2 => 10b
3 => 11b
```

then replace `0` by `4` and `1` by `7` (arbitrary), giving: `44, 47, 74, 77`